# How to correct made dispatch main queue task in block function ObjC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Loading some data from server, but loop(for .. in ..) is finishing before actually data loaded. How to correct implement dispatch on main queue or mistake in another thing?

```
[ApiManager getCategoriesifSuccess:^{
    [self.sectionArray addObjectsFromArray:[CategoryManager getCats]];
    for (CategorySectionModel *mod in [CategoryManager getCats]) {
        [self.arrayForBool addObject:@"YES"];
        [ApiManager getCatalogItemsInCity:currentCity withSection:mod.uid
                                 andStart:@"1" andLimit:@"20" ifSuccess:^{
                                     [self.itemsArray setObject:[CatalogItemManager getItems] forKey:mod.uid];
                                     [indicator stopAnimating];
                                     [self.tableView reloadData];
                                     NSLog(@"DONE WITH SECTION:%@", mod.title);
                                 } orIfFailed:^(NSString *fail) {
                                     NSLog(@"%@", fail);
                                 }];
        NSLog(@"LOOP");
    };
} orIfFailed:^{
}];
```

And console return this, but it seems not that correct:

```
2017-12-24 01:17:57.148355+0300 iOS[75679:1805296] LOOP
2017-12-24 01:17:57.149576+0300 iOS[75679:1805296] LOOP
2017-12-24 01:17:57.150786+0300 iOS[75679:1805296] LOOP
2017-12-24 01:17:57.152773+0300 iOS[75679:1805296] LOOP
2017-12-24 01:17:57.154727+0300 iOS[75679:1805296] LOOP
2017-12-24 01:17:57.156987+0300 iOS[75679:1805296] LOOP
2017-12-24 01:17:57.158840+0300 iOS[75679:1805296] LOOP
2017-12-24 01:17:57.981119+0300 iOS[75679:1805296] DONE WITH SECTION:First
2017-12-24 01:17:58.285569+0300 iOS[75679:1805296] DONE WITH SECTION:Second
2017-12-24 01:17:58.403725+0300 iOS[75679:1805296] DONE WITH SECTION:Third
2017-12-24 01:17:58.434170+0300 iOS[75679:1805296] DONE WITH SECTION:Fourth
2017-12-24 01:17:58.449970+0300 iOS[75679:1805296] DONE WITH SECTION:Fifth
2017-12-24 01:17:58.469519+0300 iOS[75679:1805296] DONE WITH SECTION:Sixth
2017-12-24 01:17:58.535116+0300 iOS[75679:1805296] DONE WITH SECTION:Seventh
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dispatch group:

Swift (pseudo code):

```
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    for ... {
        group.enter()

        someAsyncMethod({
            group.leave()
        })
    }
    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
        // you code here will be invoked after all group.leave()
    })
```

Make sure you invoke only one (!) `group.leave()` for every `group.enter()`. If there is failure callback, then success and failure callbacks must invoke `group.leave()`

Comment: The question is about Objective-C specifically.

Comment: Its seems like nothing change to me.

Comment: @IlyaChikmarev - No, this is a critical change. We assume you're intent was to know when all of the requests were done (at which point you'd probably trigger some other action). Using dispatch groups is the right way to do that (though I wish Alexander would have provided Objective-C example for you).

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is intended and it is what async dispatches are made for. Let's reduce it to a simple example:

```
[Manager doSomethingLongInBackgroundWithCompletionHandler:
^{
  NSLog( @"done" );
}];
NSLog( @"Loop" );
```

In such a case, you will see Loop first, because the execution of the main control flow continues immediately while the long background takes may take seconds, minutes and hours.

To solve that problem (it isn't a problem, because this is the intended behavior), you have to put the code that has to be executed after the completion into it:

```
[Manager doSomethingLongInBackgroundWithCompletionHandler:
^{
  NSLog( @"done" );
  NSLog( @"Loop" );
}];
```

In your case that means, that the log has to be moved inside the completion handler:

```
for (CategorySectionModel *mod in [CategoryManager getCats]) {
    [self.arrayForBool addObject:@"YES"];
    [ApiManager getCatalogItemsInCity:currentCity withSection:mod.uid andStart:@"1" andLimit:@"20" ifSuccess:
    ^{
      [self.itemsArray setObject:[CatalogItemManager getItems] forKey:mod.uid];
      [indicator stopAnimating];
      [self.tableView reloadData];
      NSLog(@"DONE WITH SECTION:%@", mod.title);
      NSLog(@"LOOP");
    } 
    orIfFailed:
    ^(NSString *fail) 
    {
      NSLog(@"%@", fail);
      NSLog(@"LOOP");
  }];
};
```

I assume, that `NSLog(@"LOOP")` is a placeholder for more relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe is correct and should be expected.

You are performing a loop of asynchronous tasks. I.e., you are looping, starting a bunch of asynchronous tasks, but the loop will finish immediately while the network requests slowly progress. So you need some way to know when all of those network requests are done so that you can, for example, stop your `indicator`.

The typical solution for this is dispatch groups.

```
[indicator startAnimating];

[ApiManager getCategoriesifSuccess:^{
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    NSArray *categories = [CategoryManager getCats];
    [self.sectionArray addObjectsFromArray:categories];

    for (CategorySectionModel *mod in categories) {
        dispatch_group_enter(group);

        [self.arrayForBool addObject:@"YES"];
        [ApiManager getCatalogItemsInCity:currentCity withSection:mod.uid andStart:@"1" andLimit:@"20" ifSuccess:^{
            [self.itemsArray setObject:[CatalogItemManager getItems] forKey:mod.uid];
            NSLog(@"DONE WITH SECTION:%@", mod.title);

            // personally I'd reload section by section, e.g.
            //
            // NSInteger section = ...
            // [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        } orIfFailed:^(NSString *fail) {
            NSLog(@"%@", fail);
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        }];
    };

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [indicator stopAnimating];
        [self.tableView reloadData]; // assuming you didn't just reload section-by-section as they finished
    });
} orIfFailed:^{
    [indicator stopAnimating];
    // display something about the nature of the error
}];
```

Having said this, I suspect you have a deeper problem, that these various methods likely have not been designed to support concurrency (i.e. that there might be several asynchronous requests going on at the same time). For example, you're calling `[CatalogItemManager getItems]` to get the items for a particular category. But if you've got multiple requests going on at the same time, that won't work. You really should change `getCatalogItemsInCity` to (a) keep the items in some local variable; and (b) pass it back as a parameter of the `success` block.

(Likewise `getCategoriesifSuccess` should probably pass the categories as a parameter to its `success` block, not relying upon `[CategoryManager getCats]`. It's less critical there (because I suspect you don't have multiple queries for categories going on concurrently), but it's still a better design.)

That might look like:

```
[ApiManager getCategoriesIfSuccess:^(NSArray *categories){
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    [self.sectionArray addObjectsFromArray:categories];

    for (CategorySectionModel *mod in categories) {
        dispatch_group_enter(group);

        [self.arrayForBool addObject:@"YES"];
        [ApiManager getCatalogItemsInCity:currentCity withSection:mod.uid andStart:@"1" andLimit:@"20" ifSuccess:^(NSArray *items){
            [self.itemsArray setObject:items forKey:mod.uid];
            NSLog(@"DONE WITH SECTION:%@", mod.title);

            NSInteger section = ...
            [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        } orIfFailed:^(NSString *fail) {
            NSLog(@"%@", fail);
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        }];
    };

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [indicator stopAnimating];
    });
} orIfFailed:^{
    [indicator stopAnimating];
    // display something about the nature of the error
}];
```

BTW, I don't know if your completion handlers are dispatched back to the main queue or not. Above, I assumed they were, but if not, you should manually dispatch all model and UI updates to the main queue.

Comment: Really good explaining and you are right for your thoughts! Now its more clear for me. Thats helps a lot!